# How do you connect to the Google Translate service using REST API?

Tags: rest, http, http-headers

This is my first time using the REST API and I'm not sure if what I'm doing is correct.

I bought a subscription to use the Google Translate service from Rapid API marketplace: https://rapidapi.com/googlecloud/api/google-translate1

When I test the above link using the "Test Endpoint" in the Endpoints tab it works.

Now I want to use it in a web app.

So I set up the endpoint that connects to the Google Translate service using a REST adapter in Oracle Integration Cloud.

In the endpoint I used the information in the above link to set up the connection. Here is what I did:

I set this as the REST API URL:

```
https://google-translate1.p.rapidapi.com/language/translate/v2
```

I set these two custom headers (I hid my actual key):

```
'X-RapidAPI-Key': '--MyKeyIsEnteredHere--',
'X-RapidAPI-Host': 'google-translate1.p.rapidapi.com'
```

I set the request body to the following json sample:

```
{
  "q" : "Hello World!",
  "target" : "es",
  "source" : "en"
}
```

And I set the response body to the following json sample:

```
{
  "translatedText" : "¡Hola Mundo!"
}
```

Here is the cURL (again hid my key):

> curl -X POST -H 'X-RapidAPI-Host: google-translate1.p.rapidapi.com' -H
> 'X-RapidAPI-Key: --MyKeyIsEnteredHere--'
> -H 'Accept: application/json' -H 'Content-Type: application/json' -d '{ "q": "Hello World!", "source": "en", "target": "es" }'
> 'https://test-frxsj5gfrkv8-fr.integration.ocp.oraclecloud.com/ic/api/integration/v1/flows/rest/TRANSLATION_INTEGRATION/1.0/translation'

Here is the error I get when trying to connect to the Google Translate service:

*"The API is unreachable, please contact the API provider", "info": "Your Client (working) ---> Gateway (working) ---> API (not working)"}.The HyperText Transfer Protocol (HTTP) 502 Bad Gateway server error response code indicates that the server, while acting as a gateway or proxy, received an invalid response from the upstream server. There could be several reasons including 1) The domain name not resolvable, 2) The origin server is down, 3) A firewall or another intermediary blocks the request. Try to replicate the same request using the same set of intermediaries using cURL or any other REST client. You can trace the cURL representation of the request sent to the target service from the Oracle Integration Cloud server logs. Try invoking the target service using cURL. If the problem persists, contact the target service admin."*